# Laravel mix npm run dev failed to parse package.json

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I am following these series https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/4, which is about Laravel 5.1 testing facilities, however I had to jump to this one https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4/episodes/3 because gulpfile.js no longer exists in Laravel, because it uses mix now, but when I try to run the cmd `npm run dev` I get the following error:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add the content of package.json

Comment: Hello, i added a print screen to the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the last `,` after the `"tdd": "...webpack.config.js"` inside your `devDependencies`

Comment: Thank you, it works now, for some reason i added that last dependency because it was not working(don't remember the error), i just read somewhere to add that tdd, but after doing what you said it works, thank you.

Comment: The tdd was supposed to be on the scripts, that was the actual issue. It is used for npm run tdd.